# Check if one date before or after another date in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, datetime

How do I check if one date is before or after another date using the Google Earth Engine Python API?

In other words, I want to compare two dates like datetime object in Python.

```
import ee
firstDate=ee.Date.fromYMD(2022,3,2)
lastDay=ee.Date.fromYMD(2022,4,1)
# Compare if firstDate >= lastDate
firstDate>=lastDate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are [server-side](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) objects, that's why your client-side comparison fails. One option could be to avoid the creation of server-side dates to begin with, and rely on Python `datetime`.

Another option is to compare `ee.Date.millis()`:

```
after = firstDate.millis().gte(lastDay.millis())
```

Note that while you could use `ee.Algorithms.If()` to do conditional logic based on these dates, it's something you should try to [avoid](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-ee.algorithms.if).

When you come to a point where you feel you need a conditional, you typically can restructure your code to avoid it. You might filter a list or collection, or do some arithmetic tricks using the fact that `firstDate.millis().gte(lastDay.millis())` returns `0` or `1`. It's all very context dependent.